# Does a transaction with a lock time need more time to be confirmed?

Tags: confirmations, multi-signature, testnet, unconfirmed-transactions, transactions

I've made this transaction in the testnet:

https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/tx/2f18c646a2b2ee8ee1f295bb5a0f5cc51c5e820a123a14b0c0e170f9777518bb

It's a multisign tx with locktime. The locktime has expired and the tx is signed, but it isn't confirmed... Does somebody know why this tx isn't confirmed?

Thanks

Comment: You may need to send it again? Nodes don't keep timelocked transactions in their mempool. It's the responsibility of the sender to make sure the transactions is stored until the locktime expires and then to broadcast the transacion. Another reason might be a too low fee, but I haven't clicked your link, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: Finally, the tx is confimed (almost a day to confirm). It's a lot of time. The fee was 0.00010001 BTC. I've tried to send another transaction with a lock time and 0.00033 fee but this isn't confirmed to past an hour. Does a tx with lock time need more time to be confirmed?

Comment: Again: did you re-send the transaction after the lock time expired?

Answer (score 1):

Mempools are constantly changing. Each node has its own policy (how much of it to keep, when it gets cleared, which ones stay when a block is found, etc) so it's difficult to know if your transaction is on the network. Generally, you can be sure that a tx with a sufficiently high locktime won't be in the blocks before that locktime, but you are not guaranteed that it will be in the blocks after for a lot of other reasons (insufficient fee and mempool turnover being the two big ones). Generally with these types of transactions, it's recommended that you broadcast after the locktime has passed.